# Laravel - Passing array of data to view and accessing array elements conditionally

Tags: laravel, email

Suppose I design an email template notifying about the interview scheduled for 3 candidates to a recruiter, so in that case I send candidates array of 3 elements as a variable to my template. How do I access individual candidates name in that case?

Comment: You can enqueue a job + pass array of three candidates. Then within the job query each candidate and with foreach loop send email to each of them. So you pass only one candidate name to each email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need to pass parameters as you would for any other, with

```
$candArr = Candidates::where('something','value')->get();
return view('email')->with('candidates',$candArr);
```

Or

```
$candArr = Candidates::where('something','value')->get();
return view('email',compact('candArr'));
```

and then in view

```
@foreach($candArr as $key)
 {{$key->name}}
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps!